# Deleting script file delete another in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am facing an issue in Xcode Run script. I have three targets Dev, Pre & Prod.  As below image in PROD target, I can see there are two duplicate scrip files

[image]

When I tried to run app in Xcode 10, I am getting duplicate error message. Now when I tried to delete an script, Xcode automatically deletes another one. I am working in Xcode 10. Run script has input files & output files. (Below image to display input output files in Script)

[image]

I have also tried to delete duplicate files in  Xcode 9.4.1 but problem is same(Code was developed in Xcode 9.4.1)

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the duplicate run script to something else?

Comment: I renamed then automatically rename other one.

Comment: It looks like a mistake in your xcodeproj. Open it in source mode, and remove it by yourself